# Why does the Python tutorial say it is an error that other scripts in the current directory will be loaded instead of libraries with the same name?

Tags: python, python-import

[The Python Tutorial chapter 6 (Modules)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) says:

> The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory. **This is an error unless the replacement is intended**.

Why is this an error? In other terms, what is the meaning of the sentence "This is an error unless the replacement is intended"?

Comment: It would be an error in the same way that using `sum` as a variable name would be an error (it makes the built-in `sum` function inaccessible). How could an unintended name clash be a good thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After initialization, Python programs can modify [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the replacement is intended. See section [Standard Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#tut-standardmodules) for more information.

Assuming you have a package (= module) installed called `fooo`. This is the package you want to use for e script.

Now, if you import it using `fooo`, everything works as intended.

Now, if there's a module in the directory mentioned above, with the same name (`fooo`), this one will replace your intended package.

The error is, that you now got imported the wrong package.

Resource: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 1):

It basically says: If you overwrite something already specified by python and this is not your intention, then it is an error. If it is intended to overwrite it, it is not an error.

Comment: @typedecker There is no minimum length requirements for answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350305/is-very-short-answer-an-answer-or-comment

Comment: If a question can be answered simply through a comment, then theres no reason to write it as an answer. An answer is expected to be explainedin  more than just one or two lines of them clarifying what the OP asked. Else, there is no difference between a comment or a answer.

Comment: @typedecker *"If a question can be answered simply through a comment"* - It can't. Ever. Unless you blatantly violate the comment box's instruction to *"Avoid answering questions in comments"*.

Answer (score 0):

The search path is a list of paths under which the python interpreter searches for any imported modules. You can view its contents in the interactive python shell by running `python3`, then `import sys; print(sys.path)` in the terminal. For me it looks like this:

`['', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Make a python script containing `import sys; print(sys.path)`, run the script and see the first entry change from an empty string to the path your python file resides in (aka your working directory):

`['/home/thomas/Downloads', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/thomas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages']`

If your python script also contained `import my_module`, upon execution the python interpreter would first search in your working directory for a file called `my_module.py` and only if it doesn't find one there will it continue searching for the module in all the usual places where third-party libraries may be installed.

**This may cause unexpected errors if you accidentally import one of your own modules instead of a third-party module you installed via pip with the same name.**